# Set New Master Authentication Password Greyed Out

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, plugins, authentication

I'm trying to use a plugin in QGIS that requires a master authentication to work. I follow the prompts to add one, but once I have filled out both required inputs I can't add it. The "ok" button is greyed out.

I have installed and reinstalled both the plugin and QGIS. Any ideas why I cant add a new authentication even with a reinstall?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, it looks like you have entered two different passwords. The idea with the two input boxes is just to verify your password - there is no username (rather the master password is tied to your user account).

Try entering the same password twice and you should be off to the races.